¿Como debería actualizar registros de productos con base en la orden que estoy recibiendo, para restar el stock?
Tengo una tabla Product y quiero actualizar el stock cuando creo una Orden de compra. Tambien tengo una tabla que relaciona de muchos a muchos ambas tablas, ya que conforman los productos que pertenecen a cada orden, llamada Productos_Ordenes
public async Task<Order> CreateOrder(Order order)
        {
            try
            {
                var filtered = order.OrderProducts
                    .GroupBy(op => op.IdProduct)
                    .Select(group => group.First())
                    .ToList();
                var newCode = Guid.NewGuid();
                var Envio = new Delivery()
                {
                    IdState = 2,
                    IdUser = order.IdUser,
                    Code = newCode.ToString()
                };
                Envio = await _unitOfWork.DeliveryRepo.CreateAndReturn(Envio);
                order.IdDelivery = Envio.Id;

                order = await _unitOfWork.OrderRepo.AddAndReturn(order);
                await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
                foreach(var op in filtered)
                {
                    var ProductForEdit = await _unitOfWork.ProductRepo.GetById(op.IdProduct);
                    if(ProductForEdit == null)
                    {
                        throw new BaseException($"NO estoy encontrando el producto ${op.IdProduct}");
                    }
                    ProductForEdit.Stock -= op.ProductsNumber;
                    _unitOfWork.ProductRepo.Update(ProductForEdit.Id, ProductForEdit);
                    await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
                    await _unitOfWork.OrderRepo.AddNewOrderProduct(op);

                    if (filtered.IndexOf(op) % 3 == 0)
                        await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
                }

                await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
                return order;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Exception al momento de realizar las operaciones", ex);
            }
            
        }

El problema es que al momento de guardar, me lanza la exception del Catch
System.Exception: Exception al momento de realizar las operaciones
 ---> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Productos_Ordenes'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Productos_Ordenes'. The duplicate key value is (1008, 3004).

El problema es que igual está creando los registros de la tabla Productos_Ordenes pero NO actualiza el stock del producto, por lo que no entiendo que está pasando
